# Pen tool: A different stroke for points

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a number of triangles that I have loosely created with the pen tool. They have no fill but a stroke of `0.25pt`. Is there anyway the points themselves can have a different stroke size? Like 1pt?

Roughly this would look like: `o.....o`, where the `o` is a pen tool point and the `...` is a line that connects the points.

Comment: Whats wrong with adding a 1pt circle on centered on each point

Comment: I suppose that's one way to go about it, but I would have to redo everything since there are hundreds of points right now. Just wondering if this is possible at the moment.

Comment: No there is no such builtin you can script it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a script that can do this.

Scroll down [this page on Design Tuts Plus](https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/20-free-and-useful-adobe-illustrator-scripts--vector-3849) to find the one named "Dup at Selected Anchors".

Download it and extract the .js file contained in the zip. Save it somewhere you can easily find it again*.

In Illustrator draw a triangle or any shape with the pen tool or a shape tool, then draw a filled small circle. Select both circle and shape. Click *File > Scripts > Other script*, and locate the script you saved previously, and run it.

Copies of the circle will be placed at all the anchor points of the shape

Here's an example using a star shape and a circle.

[image]

In case of link rot, here's [the page on web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200801172818/https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/20-free-and-useful-adobe-illustrator-scripts--vector-3849)

*Note: Alternatively you can save the script in your Adobe Illustrator scripts folder. Then you can access it directly by going to File > Scripts, and it should be listed.

Comment: Yeah there is aaletrantive one at https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/src/default/jooHandlesToGeometry.jsx that uses symbols instead.

Comment: @joojaa - nice!

Comment: It also makes tangents but you can just eliminate that step

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for both the link and the explanation on how to use it!